# Redirect home page htaccess, keep the rest

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a Joomla site with a blog attached to it.

I created a new homepage for it, though, that uses just plain html and have uploaded it to the `/new/` directory. I'm trying to write an htaccess redirect that will allow me to use the `/new/` directory just for the homepage, but still use the Joomla part for the blog.

Here's what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule ^  /new/ [L]
```

This actually redirects it in the browser to `/new/` instead of doing it underneath the hood, invisibly.  Also when I go to the `/blog/` page, it is very messed up.  In sum:

`domain.com` --> `domain.com/new/`  (but don't show the redirect)
`domain.com/*` --> allow joomla to do its thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get @anubhava solution to work, so I just moved my whole joomla installation into the /blog/ folder.  There are just a couple of changes that you have to make in the configuration.php file.   After that I put my new site in the root folder.